# Why am I getting a length mismatch error while differentiating a time series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to differentiate a time series this way:

```
#statistical test for the stationarity of the time series
from pandas import read_excel
from pandas import Series
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
# create a differenced time series
def difference(dataset):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(1, len(dataset)):
        value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - 1]
        diff.append(value)
        return Series(diff)
series = read_excel('dataset.xlsx', header=None, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
X = series.values
# difference data
stationary = difference(X)
stationary.index = series.index[1:]
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 107 elements
```

Why isn't the stationary.index catching the elements of the dataset?

Comment: Two possible reasons for me: 1) it sees is as an object; 2) when you make your operations, something "goes wrong" from your logic and makes the data only of length 1

Comment: You `return` early from the function, it only goes for `i = 1`. Try de-denting `return Series(diff)`, perhaps that's the reason.

Comment: @MustafaAydın you were right, the problem got solve by de-denting `return Series(diff)`. Thanks